# Javascript / MomentJs calculates hours right but not mins

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have 3 boxes with start hour, end hour and break and it will print out the "Worked" hour into a read only field.
How ever my javascript calculates the hour just fine, but it's not so correct when it comes to minutes.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cnmjtfhz/
[image]

But if I add 5 mins to my "Starting hour" it will end up like this:
[image]

It will remove 5 mins from the total worked hours even though it should add 5 minutes. And if I add another 5 minutes so it will be 8:10 my total time will go up to 9:00

This is my script:

```
    function CalculateTime() {
    try {
        var originalStartTime = $('#startTime').val(),
          originalEndTime = $('#endTime').val(),
          originalBreakTime = $('#breakTime').val();

        // breaking hours and minutes. needed format: HH:mm
        var startHours = originalStartTime.substring(0, 2).replace(':', ''),
          startMinutes = originalStartTime.substring(3, 5),
          endHours = originalEndTime.substring(0, 2).replace(':', ''),
          endMinutes = originalEndTime.substring(3, 5);

        // momentJs variables
        var mStart = moment().hour(startHours).minute(startMinutes),
          mEnd = moment().hour(endHours).minute(endMinutes),
          mBreak = moment.duration(originalBreakTime);

        var result = mEnd.subtract(mStart).subtract(mBreak).format('HH:mm');

        $('#workedHours').val(result);

    } catch (err) {
        $('#workedHours').val(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly provide jsfiddle link please

Comment: @Mahadevan https://jsfiddle.net/cnmjtfhz/

Comment: I don't get the point, if you start 5 minutes after, and the ending hour it's the same, it's correct that the resulting total hours are 5 minutes less. The fiddle it's working for what i understand.

Comment: yes @JoakimCarlsson kindly explain me clearly it was confusing

Comment: Sometimes 08:50 > 17:20 will end up as 08:20, and so on. It seems like it's working good when you are typing in the hours your self. But when using the Time Picker it seems to bug. I'll assume it's my time picker and look closer into that.

Comment: Just tried in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aforni/cnmjtfhz/3/) to use `<input>` with type "time" to use the time picker and the calculated result is still ok. I've set the start-end times to 08:50-17:20 and with a break time of 00:30 the result displayed is correct (08:00 hours). I still do not understand the problem. How can I help?